# Error while recording audio signal using WAV sink block in GNU radio

Tags: wav, gnuradio

I am tring to get the audio file in wav format of a received FM signal [grc used to receiver and record FM signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xnNR.png).
But I am not able to read the file using python code.

```
import soundfile as sf
data, fs = sf.read('/home/dstlab2/Downloads/fm_record_RSM_v2_22_01_2019_txt_2.wav')
```

'`data`' shows `'array([], dtype=float64)'`

Comment: that should be an edit to your question, not a comment.

Comment: have you verified with anything but Python that the sound is not actually in there?

Comment: i can hear it in audio player like VLC

Comment: so, in that case, this doesn't seem to be a GNU Radio, but a Python `soundfile` problem. I simply wouldn't use that nonstandard library (where is it from? never heard of it). Why not simply use the built-in [`wave`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) library, or `scipy.io.wavfile`?

Comment: Fine @MarcusMüller